# How to call Web API call inside custom module Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, programmatically, webapi

How can we call Web API in a custom module?

I have a third party module, in which they are sending a request with API calls. I have custom functionality where I have to redirect my page to that Web API link, so everything works smoothly

Can anyone here tell, how we can do that in Magento2? Some step by step guide?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your exact requirement ? You need just to redirect on a link ? Means say you have a controller from there you want to redirect on a link or call an API ?

Comment: Ya, If i use the default module they are using this link `ttp://m2.example.com/rest/no/V1/guest-carts/uDa31URAYN4ZGmrgPlxEHTHJdrSLR34Z/test/checkout/authorize`.

Comment: I have one button where I want to redirect to this url

Comment: See my answer. If it help you

Answer (score 0):

you call with api with plain curl in side magneto module
sharing sample example

```
$url = 'https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/cost';

$data = [
        'city' => 'bangkok',
        "customer_id" => 4
];
$customerToken = "djdjdjjddjdjdjjdjdjjdjdjdj";
$params = json_encode($data);

    try {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $customerToken,
                "Content-Type: application/json"
            ),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $result = json_decode($response, true);  

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* Constructor.
*
* @param Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
*/
public function __construct(
   Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
) {
   $this->curl = $curl;
}

/**
* @param string $url
*/
public function getApiData($url) 
{
   $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Length", 200);
   $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
   $this->curl->get($url);
   $result = $this->curl->getBody();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call to external API from inside Magento 2. Just use \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient inside your class.

Read more [here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/485).

A sample project here in [Github](https://github.com/baddwin/magento2-ongkir)

Comment: \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl should be used

Comment: can you give me pseudocode how to use that one